# How do I use the thumbnail plugin for docpad without copying the source image to "out"?

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, responsive-design, docpad

I am developing a photo-centric eBook for packaging and distribution via PhoneGap. I'm using the thumbnails plugin for DocPad along with picturefill for responsive images. I'd like to be able to refer to source photos (which are very high resolution unoptimized images) in @getThumbnail() but I do not want those source images copied to the "out" folder that will ultimately get packaged and distributed. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: There is a simple flaw with this. If the images are not in the out folder your website will not have access to that. I imagine you want the images to be in a different server/location than your website?

Comment: To understand the question you'll need some familiarity with DocPad's thumbnail plugin: https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-thumbnails The plugin's @getThumbnail() method takes a source path as an argument and generates thumbnails at various sizes based on the options you specify. I want the generated thumbnails, and I do not want the source image, in the output.

Comment: Ah OK. Well a simple solution that I can come up with is simply delete the files afterwards. Name them something unique so that your script only deletes them. That's the simple solution I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the thumbnail plugin made this suggestion via GitHub issues, and I believe it's likely to be as good an answer as any.

[docpad-plugin-thumbnails issue #4](https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-thumbnails/issues/4#issuecomment-22799439)

> Hey Jason,
>
> That's a good question. I'd probably achieve that by running a grunt task post-generation (such as https://github.com/reputation/grunt-clean) to remove all the original source files from the /out dir. To make that easier you could rename all your source files as [name].hires.jpg or similar so you can match them easier.
>
> I believe the thumbnail plugin will strip all intermediate extensions from the source filename so that image1.hires.jpg will be generated as image1.thumb_default_w100h100q85.jpg (for example). This is an unintended side effect that will work in your favor.

Comment: It's along the lines of what I suggested. :)

Comment: It's not ideal because big files are unnecessarily copied and deleted, but it doesn't take all that long.

Comment: Indeed. I suggest you make it so that only the production environment deletes the pictures. That way while developing it's faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a *URL* for the `getThumbnail('src')` !

You'll could probably fork it and add a `if` to check if there is a http at the begining of the sliced 'src' argument, else use the sysPath but I don't know if that's the most elegant solution. It might be a good one, I'm not the most confident programmer yet.

;)

Best of luck.

Comment: The thumbnail plugin expects file system paths. URLs do not work. I could fork the plugin (and may yet do that) but I wouldn't want to introduce HTTP URLs anyway. The idea is that the entire site is on your local device and can be accessed entirely offline.

Comment: Your URL's could be of localhost like the idea you had in the IRC.

Comment: As explained above, getThumbnail won't accept paths that start with HTTP. Fortunately the grunt task explained in my answer solves my problem.